# How can I automatically encode a folder of wmv files to flv?

Tags: windows-xp, video, conversion, flv, wmv

I have a folder in which .wmvs are saved after they are finished recording.  I would like to set up a script which encodes all of the files in this folder into .flvs with the appropriate size, frame rate, etc and then moves them to another folder.  I have been looking for a command line .wmv to .flv converter to do this without much success.  Has someone automatically encoded .wmvs to .flvs before that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](http://worldtv.com/blog/guides_tutorials/flv_converter.php) looks like it can help you out (though it does assume the reader is less than a "super user"!). It details using the [ffmpeg.exe](http://ffmpeg.org/) command line tool to do video conversions. ffmpeg is very well regarded, and is used as the engine to drive many GUI conversion apps.

It should just be a case of creating a batch file that calls the ffmpeg executable with the appropriate parameters, and then running that periodically, perhaps as a scheduled task.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is pretty much the defacto standard for video encoding and conversion.

There's also MEncoder which is a command line tool that comes with [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)

Both are free, open source and cross platform.

Comment: Good info.  If I could mark both answers correct, I would.  Thanks.